# Divide data frame into groups at each level

Tags: python

I want to divide my data frame at based on two columns in two stages. 1st stages will be 20 groups based on 20 integers in the first column. Then the each of those groups will be further divided into groups based on another value of the second column (200 integers, intervals of 10). Any idea how I can do this? The data frame looks something like this:

```
60 150
60 155
60 156
61 155
61 166
62 132
62 145
62 167
63 172
63 180
```

Comment: What code have you written for this so far?

Comment: Into a `list` or just `dataframe`

Comment: doesn't matter, either will work but pref dataframe

Comment: Is this for pandas, a third-party module? Please tag. Note: there is no built-in dataframe object in Python.

Comment: this is for pandas